Почему код для получения данных с ардуино работает с одним НО?
Я написал код для получения данных с ардуино, но он не работает с одним НО
Этот код не работает
import serial
ser=serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=9600)
while True:
  line = ser.readline()
  print (line)

А этот - работает
import serial
ser=serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=9600)
while True:
  line = ser.read()
  print (line)

Дело в том что read читает только по 1 байту

А что делает readline - вы в документации прочитали?

А вопрос в чем? Используйте тот вариант, который работает.

Не дублируйте один и тот же вопрос несколько раз, отредактируйте предыдущий.
